# Yii 2.0 Change selected option on dropdownlist?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

Im basically trying to change the selected option in a dropdownlist in yii 2.0

For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Now when i change the drop down to another option it submits the form , however it then displays the initial selected value not the new one.

In my view i have:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();

    echo $form->field($searchModel , 'category')->dropDownList([
        '1' => 'category 1', '2' => 'category 2', '3' => 'category 3'

        ],['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()',]);

ActiveForm::end();
```

Okay so now in my controller i capture the post values so know it is posting correctly. So lets say i have a variable $option which is equal to the post value in the drop down list.

How do i go about making this the new selected option when the page refreshes?

Everything i'm finding is to do with yii 1 not 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the post value to the `$searchModel->category` attribute at any point? Try `echo`ing it out just above the field to check. I don't know Yii 2, but if `category` is an 'unsafe' attribute it can't be massively assigned in Yii 1.

Answer (score -2):

For setting the value of dropdown in controller you can use:

```
$searchModel->category = '1';
```

For setting the value of dropdown in view:

```
$form->field($model, $key, 
                        ['options' => 
                            [
                                'class' => 'col-xs-3'
                            ]
                        ])
                    ->dropDownList(
                        your_array_of_values,
                        ['options' =>
                            [
                              array_key => ['selected ' => true]
                            ]
                        ]
                    );
```

Comment: I would appreciate if by giving downvote you also specify the reason to do so, that will help to give the proper answer :)